# Should I be using clean URLs or URL parameter in my Web App?

Tags: url, web, dashboard, saas, internal

Which URL structure should I use for my Web-app?

Clean URLs like this

```
http://dashboard.company.com/sales/john-doe/2017/32
```

or with URL parameters?

```
http://dashboard.company.com/sales?person=john.doe&year=2017&week=32
```

Are there any guidelines for this?

Edit to explain my question better From the user perspective, the two ways are identical in ways of sharing the url. For the programming part they are not, I use Flask. I want know if there's a standard way of handling it, what is the better way?

**Background**

I am developing a Sales Dashboard for internal use at my company. It display the sales of every sales person. I want to make the reports shareable so that my colleagues can send their own page for a certain weeknumber with each other, or whatever. Or the boss can easily get the page for a meeting with the sales person.

**No SEO**

Just to stress this point. I don't need clean URLs for SEO.

Comment: What do you mean *"should"*?

Comment: The first :). the second is open bar we known all the get var using by the form or a redirection and witch get value is checked or no.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter at all, by adding the parameters as GET or POST they will be visible but if you use a framework for your app, you should use clean as possible because the parameters to the controllers must be specific and not by data. Otherwise if is not a big project you can use like that but you need to make sure that soon you wont have something like lang?en or something which will be as main parameter. It's up to you, read GET x POST differences and you'll figure it out better.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "use clean as possible because the parameters to the controller must be specific..."?

Comment: Check MVC php frameworks, they work as model->view->controller and a controller is a normal php function but if you send parameters to the function it will be via url and not as POST or GET but yes after the controller name so url/controller_name/parameter if your function is waiting too but its better you read MVC framework and see how it works